# Creating a dynamic grid of pictureboxes with c#

Tags: c#

I am looking to create a dynamic grid of picture boxes that will be generated once the user enters their desired number of rows and columns.

e.g. If user enters 3x3, 9 total picture boxes will be created in a grid like form.

Currently, my code will create all the desired picture boxes, but it will indent the first one in each new column creating an awkward shaped grid.

```
        int rows = Convert.ToInt32(txtRow.Text);
        int columns = Convert.ToInt32(txtColumn.Text);

        // coordinates to place first box in the grid
        int x = 211;
        int y = 136;

        int totalBoxes = rows * columns;

        List<PictureBox> pictureBoxList = new List<PictureBox>();

        for (int i = 0; i < totalBoxes; i++)
        {
            while (i < rows)
            {
                PictureBox picture = new PictureBox
                {
                    Name = "pictureBox" + i,
                    Size = new Size(70, 60),
                    Location = new Point(x, y),
                    BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D,
                    SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
                    Visible = true
                };
                this.Controls.Add(picture);
                pictureBoxList.Add(picture);
                y = y + 59;
                break;
            }

            while (i < columns)
            {
                PictureBox picture = new PictureBox
                {
                    Name = "pictureBox" + i,
                    Size = new Size(70, 60),
                    Location = new Point(x, y),
                    BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D,
                    SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
                    Visible = true
                };
                this.Controls.Add(picture);
                pictureBoxList.Add(picture);
                x = x + 67;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: you need to reset the x position when a row is full. Or the y position when a column is full.

Comment: Also: while the Name property has no real meaning: your pboxes have non-unique Names..

Comment: @TaW `this.Controls.ContainsKey(...)` would like to have a word with you.

Comment: Sure. And my answer is: _non-unique_, close to completely useless.

Answer (score 1):

you can set picturebox locations like this:

```
PictureBox picture = new PictureBox
{
    Location = new Point(i%columns * desiredWidth, i/columns  * desiredHeight),
    ....
};
```

for example as picturebox size is (70,60), with a 5 pixel more space between you may like it as `new Point(i%columns  * 75, i/columns  * 65) //desiredWidth=75, desiredHeight=65`

You may also give it an start Indent too:

```
 Location = new Point(x+ i%columns  * desiredWidth,y+ i/columns * desiredHeight);
```

I would do it like:

```
int w=75, h = 65;
 PictureBox picture = new PictureBox
                {
                    Name = "pictureBox" + i,
                    Size = new Size(70, 60),
                    Location = new Point(x + i%columns * w, y + i/columns * h),
                    BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D,
                    SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
                    Visible = true
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use on cycle from 0 up to total picture box numbers, as you started in your code. In this case you should calculate position of each box, as [Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1079221/ashkan-mobayen-khiabani) show you, like this:

```
//  size of the boxes
Size size = new Size(70, 60);

int totalBoxes = rows * columns;
List<PictureBox> pictureBoxList = new List<PictureBox>();
for (int i = 0; i < totalBoxes; i++)
{
    int curentColumn = i % columns;
    int currentRow = i / columns;
    int curentX = x + curentColumn * size.Width;
    int curentY = y + currentRow * size.Height;
    PictureBox picture = new PictureBox
    {
        Name = "pictureBox" + i,
        Size = size,
        Location = new Point(curentX, curentY),
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D,
        SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
        Visible = true
    };
    this.Controls.Add(picture);
    pictureBoxList.Add(picture);
}
```

However, you can also use two nested loops. First goes trough all the rows and second through all the columns, like this:

```
//  size of the boxes
Size size = new Size(70, 60);
int totalBoxes = rows * columns;
List<PictureBox> pictureBoxList = new List<PictureBox>();
for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
{
    int curentY = y + row * size.Height;
    for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++)
    {
        int curentX = x + col * size.Width;
        PictureBox picture = new PictureBox
        {
            Name = "pictureBox" + (row + col),
            Size = size,
            Location = new Point(curentX, curentY),
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D,
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
            Visible = true
        };
        this.Controls.Add(picture);
        pictureBoxList.Add(picture);
    }
}
```

I personally prefer the nested loops way as it easier to read :)

From performance point of view both approaches should be the same.